# Why is my link not being passed back from Apex method using JavaScript Remoting?

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce

I have the following code that I adapted from a response to another question on Stackoverflow. I am very appreciative of the answer provided by @eyescream.

I am now trying to display a link to account objects that has come back from a JavaScript Remoting call to an Apex method. I get the name and ID, but not the URL I am passing back.

Here is the page:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="Stack73082136">
  <h1>Account Type-Ahead Search Demo VF</h1>
  <apex:form >
      <script>
      function callRemote(term){
          // call static method in ClassName.methodName format
          Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.Stack73082136.getMatchingAccounts}',
            term,
            false, // no contacts pls
            function(result, event){
                if (event.status) {
                    //debugger;
                    let target = document.getElementById("out3");
                    while (target.firstChild) {
                      target.removeChild(target.firstChild);
                    }
                    result.forEach((item) => { console.log(item.name); console.log(item.link); target.append('<A href="' + item.link + '">' + item.name + '|' + item.link + '</A>' ) } );
                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                    document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = 
                        event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
                }
            }, 
            {escape: true}
        );
      }
      </script>
      <apex:pageBlock title="3. VF remoting, the grandfather of Aura. No viewstate, pure html and js">    
          <input type="text" id="text3" label="type and vait v2" onkeyup="callRemote(this.value)" />
          <div id="out3"></div>
          <div id="responseErrors"></div>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the Apex:

```
public class Stack73082136 {
    
    // Service part (static, useable in Aura/LWC but eventually maybe also as a REST service)
    // This method would typically throw exceptions, perhaps AuraHandledException
    @RemoteAction @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static MatchingAccountsWrapper[] getMatchingAccounts(String searchString, Boolean showContacts) {
        String searchSpec = '%' + searchString + '%';
        List<Account> accountsFound;
        if (showContacts) {
            accountsFound = [
                SELECT Id, Name,
                    (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts ORDER BY Name) 
                FROM Account 
                WHERE Name LIKE :searchSpec 
                ORDER BY Name];
        } else {
            accountsFound = [
                SELECT Id, Name
                FROM Account 
                WHERE Name LIKE :searchSpec 
                ORDER BY Name];
        }

        List<MatchingAccountsWrapper> matchingAccounts = new List<MatchingAccountsWrapper>();
        for (Account ma : accountsFound) {
            MatchingAccountsWrapper mar = new MatchingAccountsWrapper(ma.Id, ma.Name, showContacts ? ma.Contacts: null);
            matchingAccounts.add(mar);
            system.debug('#@# matching account.name = ' + ma.Name);
            system.debug('#@# matching mar.name = ' + mar.name);
            system.debug('#@# matching mar.link = ' + mar.link);
        }
        return matchingAccounts;
    }
    
    // Visualforce part (old school, stateful)
    // This would typically not throw exceptions but ApexPages.addMessage() etc.
    // (which means that non-VF context like a trigger, inbound email handler or code called from Flow would crash and burn at runtime; in these you can only do exceptions)
    
    public String searchValue {get;set;}

    public List<MatchingAccountsWrapper> getMatchingAccountsVF() {
        return getMatchingAccounts(searchValue, false);
    }

    public void onKeyUpHandlerVF() {
        system.debug('#@# AccountTypeAheadSearchHelper:onKeyUpHandlerVF(): BEGIN');
        system.debug('#@# AccountTypeAheadSearchHelper:onKeyUpHandlerVF(): accountSearchVFValue = ' + searchValue);
        // do nothing. this method is "stupid", it's only job is to be called, pass the parameter and then the getMatchingAccountsVF
        // will be called by VF engine when it needs to rerender {!matchingAccountsVF} expression
    }

    public class MatchingAccountsWrapper {

        public MatchingAccountsWrapper(String k, String n) {
            key = k;
            name = n;
        }

        public MatchingAccountsWrapper(String k, String n, List<Contact> c) {
            key = k;
            name = n;
            relatedContacts = c;
        }

        public MatchingAccountsWrapper(Account a) {
            key = a.Id;
            name = a.Name;
        }

        @AuraEnabled
        public string key {get; set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        public string name {get; set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        public string link {get {
            return URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + this.key;
        } set;}

        private List<Contact> relatedContacts {get; set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        public List<MatchingContactsWrapper> contacts {get {
            if (relatedContacts != null) {
                List<MatchingContactsWrapper> matchingContacts = new List<MatchingContactsWrapper>();
                for (Contact matchingContact : relatedContacts) {
                    MatchingContactsWrapper mac = new MatchingContactsWrapper(matchingContact);
                    matchingContacts.add(mac);
                }
                return matchingContacts;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } set;}
    }

    private class MatchingContactsWrapper {

        public MatchingContactsWrapper(Contact c) {
            key = c.Id;
            name = c.Name;
        }

        @AuraEnabled
        public string key {get; set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        public string name {get; set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        public string link {get {
            return URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + this.key;
        } set;}
    }

}
```

The Apex debug log shows the link property is populated but the JavaScript console.log does not. And this is what I get displayed on my page when I search for st:

```
<A href="undefined">Express Logistics and Transport|undefined</A><A href="undefined">Pyramid Construction Inc.|undefined</A>
```

I did find that if I set the value of link in the constructors like this, it works later to just use the simple link property:

```
            key = k;
            name = n;
            link = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + k;
        }

        public MatchingAccountsWrapper(String k, String n, List<Contact> c) {
            key = k;
            name = n;
            relatedContacts = c;
            link = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + k;
        }

//        @AuraEnabled
//        global string link {get {
//            return URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + this.key;
//        } set;}

        @AuraEnabled
        global string link {get; set;}
```

I don't know why this is necessary, though. It works with this page code:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="Stack73082136">
  <h1>Account Type-Ahead Search Demo VF</h1>
  <apex:form >
      <script>
      function callRemote(term){
          // call static method in ClassName.methodName format
          Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.Stack73082136.getMatchingAccounts}',
            term,
            false, // no contacts pls
            function(result, event){
                if (event.status) {
                    //debugger;
                    let target = document.getElementById("out3");
                    while (target.firstChild) {
                      target.removeChild(target.firstChild);
                    }
                    result.forEach((item) => {
                        console.log(item.name);
                        console.log(item.link); 
                        let a = document.createElement('a');
                        let text = document.createTextNode(item.name);
                        a.appendChild(text);
                        a.title = item.name;
                        a.href = item.link;
                        a.target = '_blank';
                        target.appendChild(a);
                        let br = document.createElement('br');
                        target.appendChild(br);
                    } );
                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                    document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = 
                        event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
                }
            }, 
            {escape: true}
        );
      }
      </script>
      <apex:pageBlock title="3. VF remoting, the grandfather of Aura. No viewstate, pure html and js">    
          <input type="text" id="text3" label="type and vait v2" onkeyup="callRemote(this.value)" />
          <div id="out3"></div>
          <div id="responseErrors"></div>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ancient internet history and I might be using wrong terms, don't kill the messenger. In the olden days when Java was widely considered awesome ;) there was a concept of Beans. Simple objects to encapsulate data (but not behavio(u)r) to pass around between systems. The concept's kind of hit dead end but the term somewhat survived as [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object).

My point is - stuff you pass from Apex to Visualforce/Aura/LWC has to be simple. JSON-serializable. pure data. Primitives (integer, string, date), collections (well, Lists tend to work best really) and objects of classes built out of these primitives. Ideally fields marked `public`. Don't count on passing `transient`, `private` and functions (behavio(u)r!).

Your original code contains a getter function, not a real field.

```
public string link {get {
    return URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/' + this.key;
} set;}
```

is short hand syntax for defining 2 functions, `string getLink(),` void setLink(string s)`. (shameless plug: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/9171/799, my answer from 2013)

Since it's a function and not a real field - it's lost during serialization and passing to JS. JS will not automagically call Apex to run it whenever you're accessing this "field" - that'd be performance killer.

Make it plain old field and set it in Apex (like you already did) or create the field on the fly in JS when processing the call's results.